# Excluding saturday and sunday in angular 4 datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-cli

I am building a leave management system where a user can apply for a leave and the manager has the option to approve or decline this leave request. 
So for this there will be starting leave and ending leave date and i have to exclude saturday and sunday if they comes in between.
So if there a module which help in this? 
Ng2-datepicker doesn't have flexibility to exclude saturday , sunday or disable them on selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boostrap for this.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/channagayan/2wfnaf8r/) has an example

```
scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
        return (scope.disableWeekends && mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
      };
```

OR you can use [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

It has the option to disable days of the week(or any date) as follows

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker11'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker11').datetimepicker({
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this compatible with angular 4? And do momentjs has disable options? @channa

Comment: Edited the answer. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ok i will try this. But the fiddle has code of older angular versions

Comment: There are many options you can try. I added another one to the answer. Better try them and select whatever matches to your requirements